# Retrieve wrong response from AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, response

I'm using AFNetworking version 3.1 in Cocopods.
When call the API, the response is not correct.
Some decimal had been append on the result as below:

> {
>           RewardTopUp = 100;
>           RewardTopupGiven = 9.015000000000001;
>       }

But the correct response backend should be as below:

> {
>           RewardTopUp = 150;
>           RewardTopupGiven = 9.015;
>       }

Why the response will append a few decimal for the response object at AFNetworking?

Can someone help or someone had facing same issues?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Yes, i have faced same issue

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of number formatting. Please make sure from service and use JSON parsing